# (R) How to copy paste values from one column based on another column and ID in R

Tags: r

For simplicity reasons, let's assume I have two columns.
First: ID (string of codes such as AA23, BA53, *NA*, etc.)
Second: Age (18, 32, 55, 23, etc.)

And IDs sometimes repeat (i.e., one person - AA23 filled the survey in two days, but only on the first day was asked how old he is, but during the second and third day not).

I want to copy paste values from the Age column based on the ID, so that I have a 'long format' of the dataframe.

dput(data):

```
structure(list(Code = c("MW68", "AW80", "EW40", "BW60", "Wn36", 
"ZK45", "SI55", "MW68", "EW40", "DC06", NA, "IW28"), Age = c("52", 
"26", "34", "26", "20", "35", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L), class = "data.frame")

Input:

ID   Age
AA23 18
BA53 32
AC13 55
AA23 NA
BA53 NA  
AC13 NA
NA   23
AA23 NA
(the trick is that sometimes ID is NA)

And the desired output:
ID   Age
AA23 18
BA53 32
AC13 55
AA23 18
BA53 32  
AC13 55
NA   23
AA23 18
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you give an example of how the data actually looks like in R? I guess there will be something in that empty fields, e.g. NA or ""? Secondly, how can an ID be ```NA```? This doesn't make much sense to me. If it is ```"NA"```, you can treat it just like other text.

Comment: `Code Sex Age 
GW35   1  29  
BW44   0  21 
DW07   1  20
MW36   1  33  
NA     1  55
GW35   1  NA`  Sure, this is from head() Ok, its ugly right here, I have edited it above

Comment: You can use ```dput(data)``` on the data or a subset of it to create an output you can add to your question as code and that others can copy and paste and as a result, have the example data to work with

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about dput(), pretty useful. I have added it above. But also here: `structure(list(Code = c("MW68", "AW80", "EW40", "BW60", "Wn36", 
"ZK45", "SI55", "MW68", "EW40", "DC06", NA, "IW28"), Age = c("52", 
"26", "34", "26", "20", "35", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` : `data %>% group_by(Code) %>% fill(Age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the function `coalesce` which finds the first `NA` value and replace it with the value you define, here we would like it to be the first value of every `Age` variable (grouping variable):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(across(Age, ~ coalesce(.x, first(.x))))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   Code [10]
   Code  Age  
   <chr> <chr>
 1 MW68  52   
 2 AW80  26   
 3 EW40  34   
 4 BW60  26   
 5 Wn36  20   
 6 ZK45  35   
 7 SI55  NA   
 8 MW68  52   
 9 EW40  34   
10 DC06  NA   
11 NA    NA   
12 IW28  NA
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I've spent on it the last six hours, but you nailed it with this simple code. Worked perfectly :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped. `na.locf` function from package `zoo` mentioned earlier by Mr. @Chris Ruehlemann is also a very good and useful solution in these situations. Just keep all of these in mind and see which one would suit your problem at hand in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understood correctly what you want to do, but this code here should look where *Age* is `NA` and fill in the mean of the *Age* from the other rows with the same entry in *Code*. Obviously, this will fail if there are values for *Code* where no *Age* value exists anywhere in the table. If there are various values for *Age* in different rows with the same *Code*, it will fill in the mean in this example, since you didn't specify what to do in such a case.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(!is.na(data$Code[i])){
    if(is.na(data$Age[i])){
      data$Age[i] <- mean(data$Age[data$Code == data$Code[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
  }
}
```

This skips rows with `NA` in the *Code* column.

Comment: Thank you! It worked :D ( it turned out some NAN's, which I had to then replace with NAs, but apart of that - all good).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on `zoo`'s function `na.locf`("in the case of NA, last observation carried forward"): first you group by `Code`then you `mutate column` Age`using`ifelse `and carrying the last non-`NA` observation forward:

```
library(zoo)
data %>%
  group_by(Code) %>%
  mutate(Age = ifelse(is.na(Age), na.locf(Age), Age))
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   Code [10]
   Code  Age  
   <chr> <chr>
 1 MW68  52   
 2 AW80  26   
 3 EW40  34   
 4 BW60  26   
 5 Wn36  20   
 6 ZK45  35   
 7 SI55  NA   
 8 MW68  52   # <- value `carried forward`
 9 EW40  34   # <- value `carried forward`
10 DC06  NA   
11 NA    NA   
12 IW28  NA
```